# Обрезается URI до амперсанда при обработке XML PHP скриптом

Tags: php, xml, url

Good news, everyone!

Подскажите, пожалуйста: паршу(сю) XML файл и засовываю в MySQL нужные мне поля.

Столкнулся с тем, что URL типа [http://site.ru&аmp;ulp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site2.ru](http://site.ru&%D0%B0mp;ulp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site2.ru) обрезается до ulp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site2.ru

(ВНИМАНИЕ! В URL [http://site.ru&аmp;ulp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site2.ru](http://site.ru&%D0%B0mp;ulp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site2.ru) в примере сейчас в &аmp; стоит русская "а", иначе эти символы при публикации тут преобразовываются в обычный амперсанд, а в XML стоят именно HTML-сущности(по-моему, это так называется)).

Я уже чего только не перепробовал, и urlencode и htmlspecialchars и str_replace - ничего не получается, обрезается и всё тут.

php код такой (взял с просторов Инета) :

```
  $elements  = null;  // просто имя текущей ноды
  $offer = null; // собирает один элемент offer

  // Вызывается, когда встречается открывающий тег.
  // если это offer - создаем массив под него
  function startElements($parser, $name, $attrs)  
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if ($name == 'OFFER') {
        $offer = array();
      }
      $elements = $name;
  }

  // Вызывается, когда тег закрывается
  // если это тег offer - печатаем содержимое и вычищаем
  function endElements($parser, $name) 
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if(!empty($name)) {
          if ($name == 'OFFER') {
             echo "$offer[URL]";
            $query = "INSERT INTO shop SET name='".addslashes($offer[NAME])."', img = '".addslashes($offer[PICTURE])."', url = '".addslashes($offer[URL])."', description = '".addslashes($offer[DESCRIPTION])."', price = ".$offer[PRICE].", cat = ".$offer[CATEGORYID]."";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());      
            if($result) {echo "Загрузка завершена! ";
            } else {echo "Что-то пошло не так!";}   ;         


        $offer = null;
          }
    $elements = null;
      }
  }

  // Вызывается для текста, заполняем массив
  function characterData($parser, $data) 
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if(!empty($data)) {
          if ($elements == 'NAME' || $elements == 'PRICE' || $elements == 'PICTURE' || $elements == 'DESCRIPTION' || $elements == 'CATEGORYID') {
           $offer[$elements] = trim($data);

          } elseif( $elements == 'URL') {

             $offer[$elements] = $data;//ЗАГАДКА С АМПЕРСАНДОМ!!!
          }
      }
  }

  // Собственно, подготавливаем парсер
  $parser = xml_parser_create();

  xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startElements", "endElements");
  xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, "characterData");

  // открываем файл
   if (!($handle = fopen($url, "r"))) {
       die("could not open XML input");
   }

   while($data = fread($handle, 1024)) // читаем по кусочкам
   {
    xml_parse($parser, $data);  // и стравливаем парсеру
   }

   xml_parser_free($parser); // почистим за собой.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы URL не резался?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: То есть, вы взяли скрипт из интернета, не разобрались в нём, он делаете что-то не так, и вы хотите, чтобы мы разобрались за вас? Сейчас поищу однострочник на Perl, момент...

Answer (score 1):

Решено! При обработке данных, встречая амперсанд, этот парсер обрезает строку, не сохраняя её предыдущую часть. Всё для экономии ресурсов!
Чтобы сохранилась вся строка, нужно сконкатенировать её части:

```
 $offer[$elements] .= $data;//РАЗГАДКА С АМПЕРСАНДОМ!!!
```

Всем большое спасибо.